# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error in C# implementation of FAXCOMEX LIb

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fax

Here's the problem.

I wrote a Windows service in C# (Visual Studio 2012) which queries a MS SQL database and then uses FAXCOMEXLIB to send a fax.

I am able to reference FAXCOMEXLIB and use the server class and fax document class.
Faxes are created and sent.

However when I try to use any other class in the FAXCOMEXLIB library I get the following error when I run the service (It compiles without any errors):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040111): Retrieving the COM class 
factory for component with CLSID {43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59} failed due to 
the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)).
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
```

This is triggered by

```
FAXCOMEXLib.FaxOutgoingArchive faxOutgoing = new FAXCOMEXLib.FaxOutgoingArchive();
```

I tried to run

```
 regsvr32.exe fxscomex.dll
```

It didn't help.

I have also tried to manually create and import following registry keys.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59}]
@="FaxOutgoingArchive Class"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59}\InprocServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,66,00,78,00,\
73,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,65,00,78,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59}\ProgID]
@="FaxComEx.FaxOutgoingArchive.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990CB94669148F59}\Programmable]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59}\TypeLib]
@="{2BF34C1A-8CAC-419F-8547-32FDF6505DB8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59}\Version]
@="1.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{43C28403-E04F-474D-990C-B94669148F59}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="FaxComEx.FaxOutgoingArchive"
```

The registry keys did not help.
I have tried to run the service on Windows 7 64Bit, Windows Server 2012 64Bit and Windows Server 2008 32 bit with same exact result.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I know this is late, but can you tell me if you used the LocalSystem account in your Windows Service to send your fax? We are having an issue where FaxComExLib sends the fax but the fax does not appear in the Windows Fax outbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in your code, you are not supposed to create an instance of FaxOutgoingArchive yourself.  It is explicit in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To create a FaxOutgoingArchive object in Microsoft Visual Basic, retrieve the OutgoingArchive property of the FaxFolders object.

In case that's confusing, the same rule applies to C#